# Why are wheels so important for racing?

Tags: wheels, racing

I hear/read everywhere that if you can spend some extra money on the bike, buy better wheels. can someone explain for me why? 
Is it because they are rotating or are there other comfort factors?
thanks

Comment: I don't say this is a duplicate, but a logical extension to your question is to ask about rims and rim depth (think about when you see time trials, or track, where wheels are often solid disks). There's a good question [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/are-aerodynamic-rims-worth-additional-weight) (among others) touches this subject.

Comment: Wheels are important because the front forks kinda dig into the ground if you don't have them, har har.

Comment: It's good to have wheels that run smooth and true, and wheels are a major part of overall wind resistance.  But most riders would never notice the difference between a $100 wheel and a $1000 wheel.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: "most riders" is very generic. If you mean most riders who are into racing or interested in racing, then I think that most of them will be able to tell a 100 from a 1000 wheelset.

Comment: @cherouvim - It would be interesting to somehow do a "blind" test of that.  Concert violinists can't tell the difference between a $2000 violin and a $200,000 one.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: That's maybe because there isn't much difference in violins of that price range. For wheels though, the price range you mentioned does make a difference, both in MTB and road bikes.

Comment: That's what the concert violinists thought.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Subjective judgement may be poor, but when you have precise measurement, objective judgement is possible.  Ride a 10% grade full strength at 320 watts for 5 minutes, measured with watt meter and timer.  Change to a total (bike+rider) 2% lighter setup.  Ride that same grade again at 320 watts - but this it is completed in only 4 minutes and 44 seconds.  And you've regained your Strava KOM. :)  That said, if a $1k wheel is not strong enough to support a riders weight, riding style, and terrain, for a particular ride in question, it can be far far worse than a sturdy $100 wheel.

Comment: @CraigHicks - 2% lighter is on the order of 4 pounds/2 kilos.  The difference in weight between a fancy wheelset and only a "decent" one is on the order of ounces.  And a 10% grade is fairly steep -- the weight difference will have virtually no effect on the flat.

Comment: In the actual scenario I was describing, I was riding a steel cross bike the first time, and a carbon racing bike the second.  Both times I used the same wheels and tires: Velocity A23 with 28 round spokes back and front, 25mm Conti GPSII tires.  // "virtually no effect on the flat" - that's why expensive wheel are aero for the flat and downslopes, where aero makes a big difference - then must use costly methods and materials to keep the weight down while keeping the rim high and the wheel stiff enough.  // Many people want speed so they can race, or go on fast group rides. Purpose exists.

Comment: Per the [help center](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment): Comments should not be used for “...secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead.”

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wheels and tires are the interface between the bike and the road; and are the parts that take the most stress (wear and tear) along with the bottom bracket. (IMO)

- lighter wheels will reduce the rotating mass (rotational inertia); you will need less energy to make the wheels accelerate/decelerate.
- higher quality bearings in the hub will reduce friction.
- better aerodynamics in the rim and spokes (less energy needed to cut through air)

IMO, In the end it all matters to weight.

If you are doing serious cycling (i.e. keeping time, strava segments, ... ) it might be a good upgrade; but if you are a little less serious about it, maybe just an expensive christmas gift to self. :-)

Comment: Buy or buy :) that is nice!

Comment: Don't forget that a tire upgrade brings instant gratification up front as well for not a lot of money.  You might not notice a weight difference in other components but going form a cheap OEM tire to a quality street tire which improves rolling resistance or puncture resistance can be a big improvement upfront.

Comment: Does stiffness play apart, if so, how (e.g. Deep V)?

Comment: I agree with most of Max's answer, but wanted to link to an article that did some weight vs. aero testing (note: the writers sell some heavier aero wheels so there may be bias).

http://flocycling.blogspot.com/2014/01/flo-cycling-great-debate-aero-vs-weight.html

The crux of it is that in most cases aero is more important than weight.

Comment: The whole "rotational inertia" thing is bogus.  On a bike weight is weight.  There is a *very slight* increase in inertial from having weight on the wheel rim vs elsewhere, but it's miniscule.

Comment: I'll disagree with that.  I seriously notice in the winter when I change between wheelsets on my fatbike.  A pound and a half of weight in the wheelset (tyres and rims) is far more noticeable than when I add a pound and a half of X to my frame bag (or my body).

Comment: @ChrisinAK - When you change tires you change tread pattern.  I'm guessing your winter tires are thicker and knobbier, making for significantly increased rolling resistance.

Comment: Tread pattern is actually the same.  The main difference is the rim weight/width.

Answer (score 7):

Wheels are an easy upgrade to make as you can put them on your bike immediately with little mechanical hassle.

There are many factors related to a wheel's performance, but the one that makes the greatest difference to energy/power demand, speed and accelerations is aerodynamics. Hence why one of the most popular upgrades is to wheels with better aerodynamic properties. Wheel weight is generally way over rated as a factor in performance, and I'll come back to that later.

Factors other than aerodynamics and weight include:

- strength
- durability
- ability to stay round and true
- lateral stiffness
- cost
- repair-ability and service cost
- suitability for the purpose/race/riding situation
- braking demands
- handling characteristics
- available tyre choices
- bearing and freehub quality
- rules of competition
- suitability for the bike (e.g. will it fit?)
- sex appeal / bling factor

and so on.....

Even adding weight to a wheel rim in order to improve aerodynamics is a good trade off. However don't get sucked into thinking that the performance improvement will turn you into a racing star. The performance improvement is incremental, not revolutionary, and other factors are important when training or rolling around town.

While reducing a wheel rim's mass does give you very slight advantage during accelerations (it has no impact on steady state riding), improving the wheel's aerodynamics is by far more important.

A heavier but more aero wheel will still accelerate faster (or require less power to accelerate at the same rate), and it will attain higher speeds (or require less power to sustain any given speed). This is also true even when climbing, except when the climb gets very steep (how steep depends on your individual power, mass and aero properties).

Here is a blog post with more detailed example of the small impact to performance of adding mass to your wheel's rims, and how that extra mass is worth it if it results in better aerodynamics, even for the hardest acceleration scenario there is on a bike, a standing start:

[The sum of the parts II](http://alex-cycle.blogspot.com.au/2014/12/the-sum-of-parts-ii.html)

Comment: The hub is very important too, imo

Comment: Agree, which is why I mentioned it in the (non-exhaustive) list.

Comment: Yea, I mean that you lumped it with other minor factors where I would have it in higher regard than aerodynamics

Comment: In what sense are hubs more important than aero? Maybe I misunderstand what you are referring to. e.g. consider two wheels of comparable build quality but where one is designed with aerodynamic rims and spokes? Hubs bearings account for a tiny fraction of the energy demand (<1W), at least an order of magnitude less than the aerodynamic drag of a wheel or perhaps closer to 2 orders of magnitude difference. Halving hub friction drag would still be far smaller reduction in energy demand than attainable with a modest wheel aerodynamic gain.

Comment: No, I'm comparing between different wheels. I'd take the pair with better hubs rather than the one with better aero. You can get by with very bad aerodynamics but not with very bad hub (don't add little parachutes to spokes ofc). I guess we have different wheels in mind. Been riding some half stuck wheels lately I tell you aerodynamics were my last complain :) you sure are right if it is about new to buy wheels, as the op seems to be referring

Comment: Also, wheel aerodynamics are tricky, what is good for flat is not good uphill, and side wind s, etc, while a good hub will always be an advantage

Comment: Well the OP was asking about racing wheels, not comparing with some old rusty clunkers. As for hillclimbs, aero still matters there too and more than the tiny hub frictional differences between (new) wheels. It depends on gradient and the W/kg of the rider but for a good amateur racer the aero benefits still outweigh wheel weight differences up to gradients of ~7-8%, let alone tiny hub frictional differences. And besides, you present a false dichotomy. One can have aero wheels with good hubs.

Comment: As for cross winds, wheels perform differently yes, and handling is a factor hence why I stated suitability for the riding situation - but that's not a factor for which hubs play a part. Note that well designed aero wheel rim shapes actually get *more* aerodynamic with increased yaw angles, not less. IOW their benefit increases with cross winds. At least up to a point where excessive cross winds cause other issues.

Comment: Upvoted exclusively for the first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

[My knowledge is not racing-specific, but as they say, any time two bicycles are moving in the same direction, it’s a race.]

Hand-built wheels will tend to be [stronger and more reliable than machine-built wheels](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/why-are-hand-built-wheels-considered-to-be-better-than-machine-built-wheels). That is only very loosely true, but the way it was explained to me by an experienced wheelbuilder in a large local shop was that wheelbuilding machines can turn out wheels just as good as hand-built, but to do so the output speed has to be turned way down. This brings up the finished cost of the wheel to a point where the insanely expensive machine has no cost advantage over the human, so is rarely if ever done.

A more rigid wheel will transmit more energy to the ground because any deformation is inherently a loss of energy, or least a diversion of energy away from your goal of going forward quickly.

Lighter wheels give you a large advantage, as rolling weight matters much more than static weight. How much is a matter of some debate, and I find the [2x value given here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/185/how-can-you-speed-a-road-bike-up?lq=1) to be overly pessimistic, but it’s still definitely more than 1x.

Better spokes matter, too. Spoked wheels are an aerodynamic cluste— well, they’re [extremely sub-optimal](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/rinard/aero/aerodynamics.htm). So more [aerodynamic spokes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6088/what-are-the-advantages-or-disadvantages-of-different-spoke-styles) will help considerably. As will lacing patterns with lower spoke count (which also help with weight), although those sacrifice some durability.

Now as to whether all those improvements will help? I am of the opinion that even for those of us who aren’t competing (but see qualifier statement above), anything that makes us *feel* like we are riding faster and/or with less effort is helpful in that it increases effective endurance. In other words, if you make a cyclist feel faster and/or more powerful, they will tend to ride more, which will, over time, make them faster and/or more powerful.

Comment: *rolling weight matters much more than static weight* -- It matters a *little* more, and only for acceleration.  Weight on wheel vs frame has no effect at all on rolling resistance.

Answer (score 3):

You win non-TT bike races by being able to accelerate just that little bit much more than your competition. 99.9% of the time you are riding exactly the same speed as everyone else, what makes the difference between winning and losing is your ability to accelerate just a bit better than your competitors.

Humans are very low power engines. Since F = MA, one of the easiest ways to increase A is to decrease M. Low weight, low drag wheels will help you accelerate faster. Since wheels are rotational mass, you get a bigger bang for your buck in reducing their weight.

Bike racers obsess over the weight of gear to improve their ability to get to speed, reducing weight generally doesn't help your average speed much ( except when climbing a long hill).

Comment: This isnt really correct. Numerous academic papers have identified that in the vast majority of racing scenarios, the impact of aerodynamics substantially  exceeds the impact of weight. Even the minor benefit gained from spinning up a lighter wheel out of a corner is negated rapidly by the aerodynamic inefficiency. Unless youre riding up and down <insert mountain range here> all day, really lightweight wheels are just something to brag about in the pub ;)

Answer (score -3):

Less rotational mass can be felt immediately, even 200 grams.  It would be incredibly evident right away in acceleration.  The number one thing I hear people say after buying stock bikes is they got a new wheelset and "it feels like a new bike".  Now, it's been proven why complete with formulas.

https://www.wired.com/2016/06/cycling-physics-extra-mass-bike-wheels-enemy/

Comment: Umm... your link says exactly what Daniel R Hicks wrote above, rotational mass matters a little more  - but only during acceleration. I'm editing your answer to remove the ad hominem. You may still be downvoted for other reasons, but at least it isn't for an ad hominem.

Comment: As a physicist myself, I couldn't stop giggling when I read the rotational mass weight weenies (i hope that's not ad hominem) theories on a cycling blog the first time. (Assuming not a lot of people here are doing 1 km track time trials where it might matter in the <1% area.)

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Crankdango. As with all new members we recommend that you take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're answering see [answer] also. Enjoy